# Setting value of BrowsableAttribute at runtime

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes

I wanted to set a value of `BrowsableAttribute` for some of `MyClass` instance's properties at runtime:

```
 public class MyClass
{
     [Browsable(true)]
     public int P1 { get; set } 
     ...
}
```

Please advise how it can be done as well as how to add `BrowsableAttribute` to a `MyClass` instance's property at runtime if this attribute doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom type descriptor - which intercepts the the attribute on the way to whatever is using it. Thus having an effect which looks like the attribute is changing.

See - [Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx), [Part2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163804.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, Courtney, that ICustomTypeDescriptor interface implementation should be helpful to solve my task, and AFAIS from the articles you referred here there are quite a few other appications of this C# programming technique.

Answer (score 5):

You can't - unless you intercept loading the assembly. The attributes are stored in metadata, and loaded with the assembly, and attributes should generally be immutable (as `BrowsableAttribute` is).

Basically attributes aren't *meant* to be modified at execution time.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, Jon.

Answer (score 1):

You sort of can. I'm trying something like this at the moment, which I managed to get working with CategoryAttribute. Currently though, this stops the propertiesgrid from working all together though, even though this is being called in the constructor of a button:

```
Dim PC As PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Me)
For i As Integer = 0 To PC.Count - 1
        Dim att As BrowsableAttribute = DirectCast(PC(i).Attributes(GetType(BrowsableAttribute)), BrowsableAttribute)
        If Not att Is Nothing Then
            If att.Browsable = True Then
                Dim cat As Reflection.FieldInfo = att.GetType.GetField("Browsable", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
                If Not cat Is Nothing Then
                    cat.SetValue(att, False)
                End If
            End If
        End If
Next
```

Hope this helps